# Using @Version column does not allow @ManyToOne relationship property as a reference

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, optimistic-locking, relational-model

I'm using hibernate 3.6.3.Final. I have two relational entities A & B with a unidirectional ManyToOne defined as:

```
@Entity public class A {
...
@Version @Column ( name = "ChangeNumber" )
public Long getVersion() { return version; }
@ManyToOne @JoinColumn( name = "B_ID" )
public B getRelationalB() { return relationalB; }
...
}

@Entity public class B {
@Version @Column ( name = "ChangeNumber" )
public Long getVersion() { return version; }
....
}
```

Now suppose I have a B instance persistent in db already with pk id = 1, then doing the following operation:

```
A a = new A();
a.setRelationalB( new B( 1 ) );
session.saveOrUpdate( a ) ;
```

throws an the famous "TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient..." exception.
Surprisingly enough, if @Version @Column is removed or made @Transient, the above code would work perfectly fine. 
Any idea why i'm observing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not using the entity B which is in the database

```
A a = new A();
// you're instantiating a "new" B with id 1, this is not the same 
// as the "object" you have in the database.
a.setRelationalB( new B( 1 ) );   
session.saveOrUpdate( a ) ;
```

The problem is that hibernate cannot recognize that the new B you created is the same one as the one stored on the db. If you want to know the reason behind this, read about the [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern.

try doing something like

```
B b = sessions.get(B.class, 1)
A a = new A();
a.setRelationalB( b );
session.saveOrUpdate( a ) ;
```

On another point: if you want to save the new instances of both objects in one go, then you'll need to do a [cascade](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade).

Comment: But the first code block would work (persist A with relational B) if I don't use @Version column. Is it by chance/coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

I had "object references an unsaved transient..." exception a lot after adding the @Version column, too. **Here's how I solved it in my case:**

In my scenario the problem was on the foreign keys. The code was written so that **instead of loading the referred object it was creating a new instance and setting the primary key** hoping that Hibernate would be able to find the real one. I repeat: it worked fine before the @Version thing.

Illustrating:

Consider an object of class `B` with id `1` exists on the database and now we're saving a new instance of `A`.

- **previously (no good)** (was giving exception after @Version added):

  a.setB(new B(1));

  sf.getCurrentSession().save(a);
- **fixed (working well)** - using @Version with no problems:

  a.setB((B) sf.getCurrentSession().get(B.class, 1));

  sf.getCurrentSession().save(a);

When debugging Hibernate I find out it does some extra checking when the @Version column is present.

So, I believe people having this error either aren't loading objects they're trying to make reference to (which is a better practice anyway) **or** they're really trying to save a new instance of `B`(for example) but didn't configure cascade save for it.